# Javascript - I'd like to show the checkbox check before a long running function runs

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunc()" />
```

myFunc is somewhat long running, about a second, and the browser shows the check for the checkbox AFTER the function completes. This causes lots of issues with users.

I'd like the check to show up immediately and then the onlick function to run. Can that be done?

I know I should get the function to run faster, or redesign the user interface, but that's another issue for another time.

thanks

Comment: Which browsers are causing your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="setTimeout(myFunc, 0);" />
```

Comment: Why 0? it's the same as `onclick="myFunc();"`

Comment: I think the point is you don't want to block the thread.  setTimeout will call back in 0ms and execute your function, meanwhile the UI thread had re-painted the checkbox.

Comment: No it just get added to the event queue and the browser finishes the default behavior, then after that it starts processing the event queue again and then it executes `myFunc`. Edit:(some thing in the lines of Mike's comment)

Comment: thanks, I will try that, I have a complication in that my function passes an arguement: myFunc(this). How would I add that to the setTimeout?

Comment: `setTimeout(function(){ myFunc(arg0, arg1...); },0)`

Answer (score 0):

first of all you should not use `onclick="myFunc()"`

here's my solution:

```
$(function() {
    $("input[tpe='checkbox']").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).attr("checked", "checked");
        // your code here ...
    });
});
```